# How to retrieve `custom_disclaimer_responses` in Facebook lead gen webhook data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have set up a webhook that gets data submitted from a lead gen ad on Facebook.

In my response I have access to `field_data` and can see names and email address coming through but can't seem to find where the `custom_disclaimer_responses` is.

I am using the graph API explorer to send test submissions and getting a successful response

[image: Graph API example]

My webhook code is as follows:

```
exports.webhook = function (req, res, next) {
    var lead = req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value;
    var leadID = lead.leadgen_id;
    var formID = lead.form_id;
    var customDisclaimerResponses = lead.custom_disclaimer_responses

    fs.readFile(config.token, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err', err)
            throw err;
        }

        var content = JSON.parse(data);

        if(!content.access_token) {
            console.log('Facebook Access Token is invalid.');
            res.sendStatus(400);
        } else {
            FB.options({accessToken: content.access_token});

            FB.api('/' + leadID, function (response) {
                if(response && response.error) {
                    console.log('error', response.error);
                    res.sendStatus(400);
                } else {

                    var fields = response.field_data;

                    // do stuff here with fields

                    // Response moved to outside of above function block since Facebook will
                    // stop sending updates if the webhook starts giving errors repeatedly.
                    res.sendStatus(200);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Example of response:

```
{ created_time: '2016-11-17T09:52:44+0000',
  id: '<id>',
  field_data: 
   [ { name: 'email', values: [Object] },
     { name: 'first_name', values: [Object] },
     { name: 'last_name', values: [Object] },
     { name: 'city', values: [Object] },
     { name: 'date_of_birth', values: [Object] } 
   ] 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: How to retrieve custom disclaimer responses]

I don't use webhooks, but I think this can help you:
You can add the parameter fields=custom_disclaimer_responses to get the data you need.

I re-join collected data (the ones in field_data got without parameter) by user id

This is my PHP code, for example:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/$leadForm/leads?access_token=".$appToken;
$urlCustom = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/$leadForm/leads?fields=custom_disclaimer_responses&access_token=".$appToken;
```